# Getting start and end date of a PHP DatePeriod object?

Tags: datetime, date, php

How can i get the start and end date of a `DatePeriod` object?

```
$today  = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d')); // 2012-05-30
$period = new \DatePeriod($today, new \DateInterval('P1M'), 1);

$stats = new UsageStatistics($period);

class UsageStatistics
{

    protected $period, $sentEmailCount, $autoSentEmailCount;

    public function __construct(\DatePeriod $period)
    {
        $this->period = $period;

        // Current logged in user and email repository
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $repo = $this->getEmailRepository();

        // Get the start and end date for the given period
        $startDate = ...
        $endDate   = ...

        $result = $repo->getAllSentCount($user, $startDate, $endDate);

        // Assigning object properties
    }

    public function getSentEmailCount() { return $this->sentEmailCount; }

    public function getAutoSentEmailCount() { return $this->autoSentEmailCount; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/DatePeriod) only implements the Traversable interface and has no other methods to either access elements or retrieve them.

You can do something easy to get start/end dates:

```
$periodArray = iterator_to_array($period);
$startDate = reset($periodArray);
$endDate = end($periodArray);
```

Comment: So ugly you have to loop. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah I know, I've tried with ArrayObject but it didn't worked.

Comment: Funny, right know I was looking for exactly the same. It's seems, that there exists a patch out there https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53439 But it's from 2010, so ... don't know

Comment: @Boby: Updated to [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) which does the job here.

Comment: Cool, didn't know this function :)

Comment: I assume, that `iterator_to_array` will do exactly the same, thus you should at least not expect a performance boost. However, I can't imagine, that iterating over small periods (lets say: 5 occurences) will take much time.

Comment: I have created a PR (https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/878) that will hopefully be reviewed/merged soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHP 5.6.9 and it seems that you can use the properties `end` and `start` to access your beginning and end `DateTime` objects:

```
$p = new DatePeriod($s, $i, $e);
$startTime = $p->start; //returns $s
$endTime = $p->end; //returns $e
```

The PHP documentation doesn't seem to reflect this. I did a `print_r` of a DatePeriod object and got the following output:

```
DatePeriod Object
(
    [start] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-06-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
        )

    [current] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-06-08 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
        )

    [end] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-06-08 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
        )

    [interval] => DateInterval Object
        (
            [y] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [d] => 7
            [h] => 0
            [i] => 0
            [s] => 0
            [weekday] => 0
            [weekday_behavior] => 0
            [first_last_day_of] => 0
            [invert] => 0
            [days] => 
            [special_type] => 0
            [special_amount] => 0
            [have_weekday_relative] => 0
            [have_special_relative] => 0
        )

    [recurrences] => 1
    [include_start_date] => 1
)
```

It seems that properties `current` and `interval` are also visible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by @hakre and @Boby is not correct.

The `$endDate` is end of the period when `PERIOD % INTERVAL = 0`.

All other cases `$endDate` will be `END - PERIOD`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$startingDate = new DateTime($startingDay);
$startingDate->modify('previous day');
$startingDate->modify('next Sunday');
     
$endingDate   = new DateTime($endingDay);
$endingDate->modify('next day');
   
$period = new DatePeriod($startingDate, new DateInterval('P1W'), $endingDate);
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.